# How can a create horizontal line for my bar high on a specified time frame and session of the chart in pine editor

Tags: editor, pine-script

Need help in trading view Pine editor.

How can i Automatically draw an horizontal line based on bar high and low for a specified time frame and session. I need to have a horizontal line drawn for the highest and lowest value of the bar on the 15 minutes time frame chart and exactly for the bar of 9:30 session of Indian time (IST)

Answer (score 0):

```
// This source code is subject to the terms of the Mozilla Public License 2.0 at https://mozilla.org/MPL/2.0/
// © flashgekko
// https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-docs/en/v4/essential/Sessions_and_time_functions.html#:~:text=working%20with%20time-,The%20%E2%80%9Ctime%E2%80%9D%20function%20and%20variable,%E2%80%9D%20and%20%E2%80%9CSession%20bars%E2%80%9D
//@version=4
study("Project 002", overlay=true)


var h = high
var l = low
 
if (high > high[1]) and high >h
    h := high

if (low < low[1]) and low <l
    l := low

t = time("15","0900-1800")

if na(t[1]) and not na(t) or t[1] <t
    l:= low
    h:= high
    

plot(h, color = color.green) 
plot(l, color = color.red)
```